# How to format the IDs for a timeseries database in GridDB?

Tags: python, database, griddb

I have a timeseries database, and it has a column called `user_id`. The user ids are in this format 0000,
0001, 0002, 0003, 0004,... However, I would like to add something like a "tag" at the beginning of
every id, to mark that the timeseries is for a particular device. For example, is there a way I could make
the ids look like this: CAM_0000, CAM_0001, etc? Is that feasible in GridDB, Python?

```py
'''
FROM:
  user_id | value
----------+----------
     0000 | 18745.14
     0001 | 35981.77
     0002 | 12747.45
     0004 | 89775.32

TO:
      user_id | value
--------------+----------
     CAM_0000 | 18745.14
     CAM_0001 | 35981.77
     CAM_0002 | 12747.45
     CAM_0004 | 89775.32
'''
```

I know that the `user_id` column has integer features, so perhaps there will be a type conversion or
something.

Comment: Do you want to store these prefixes in the database? Or is this just for display purposes?

Comment: It will also help if you show your code that outputs the first table.